# Imprimir consultas laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy haciendo haciendo un proyecto, soy nuevo en php y laravel, lo que quiero hacer es cuando hago una consulta poder imprimir aparte ya se generando un reporte en pdf o abriendo una vista con esos datos, he tratado de todo y no puedo. comparto el codigo y caputuras de lo que tengo.

[image: Esta es la vista donde hago la busqueda filtro como quiero los resultados de la consulta y me los muestra en un table y lo que quiero es que al dar imprimir me impresa ese resultado]

este es la funcion que para las consultas en el controlador

```
public function consultas(Request $request)
{
    $areas = Area::all();

    $start = Carbon::parse($request->start)->startOfDay();  //2016-09-29 00:00:00.000000
    $end = Carbon::parse($request->end)->endOfDay(); //2016-09-29 23:59:59.000000

    $ConsultaVisita = RegistrarVisitas::Nombre($request->nombre)->Departamento($request->departamento)->DateBetween($start, $end)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    return view('visitas.consultas')->with(compact('ConsultaVisita', 'areas'));
}
```

y este es el codigo en el modelo uso quieryscope para las consultas

```
class RegistrarVisitas extends Model
{
    use DateTranslator;

    protected $table = 'visitas';
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'departamento', 'asunto', 'created_at'];

    public function scopeNombre($query, $nombre)
    {
        return $query->where('nombre', 'LIKE', "%$nombre%");
    }

    public function scopeDepartamento($query, $departamento)
    {
        return $query->where('departamento', 'LIKE', "%$departamento%");
    }

    public function scopeDateBetween($query, $start, $end) 
    {
        return $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
    }
}
```

espero haberme explicado lo que quiero hacer y poder contar con su apoyo.

---

esto es lo que quiero hacer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el boton imprimir consulta aun no hace una funcion y no tengo un codigo porque no se como hacerlo . alaguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es tu problema ¿algún error en la consulta? muestranos el codigo de imprimir consulta, de todos modos para crear PDFs puedes usar este paquete de laravel barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: De hecho supuestamente ya estás imprimiendo datos en tu vista, sino tu tabla que muestras en tu imagen no mostrara nada. Edita tu pregunta. Si quieres retornar solo datos tal vez esto te funcione:  return array($ConsultaVisita, $areas); Y si quieres hacer un pdf puedes ocupar el paquete que te sugirió el compañero de arriba.

Comment: si ya estoy imprimiendo la consulta en la misma visto lo que quiero es que hago la consulta, me la muestra en la misma vista y doy en el boton imprimir consulta me imprima esos datos, y es lo que no encuetro como hacerlo por eso no tengo un codigo que haga eso

Comment: esto es lo que quiero hacer
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj3PM.jpg

el boton imprimir consulta aun no hace una funcion y no tengo un codigo porque no se como hacerlo . alaguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Con el código que tienes puedes usar las variables que pasas en el compact hacía la vista.

En este caso tú estas pasando dos: "ConsultaVisita" y "areas", entonces en la vista puedes hacer uso de ellas, como una variable normal $ConsultaVisita y $areas.

Comment: si asi lo hice pero no me manda los datos de la consulta como deben de ser

Comment: Y como uso esas variables en otra función por ejemplo en la función imprimir, en el código tengo la función consultas, ahi me manda a la vista consultas y que es la caputra que puse anterior mente, luego quiero que los resultados de la consulta que se almacenan en la variable $ConsultaVisita, los pueda mandar a otra vista ya probe de todo y no me manda los datos que son